# OpenGL GLUT mouse movement

Tags: opengl, mousemove

I wrote a mouse function for the camera.
It works good. But the only problem is at the start, when I do first move with mouse it jumps up-left and then it works good. I don't understand why it happens.

Here the mouse function.

```
float lastx = 0.0;
float lasty = 0.0;

void mouseMovement(int x, int y) 
{
    lastx = (float)x - lastx;
    lasty = (float)y - lasty;

    if((float)x > lastx)
        Camera.RotateY((-lastx)*0.01);
    else
        Camera.RotateY(lastx*0.01);
    if((float)y > lasty)
        Camera.RotateX(lasty*0.01);
    else 
        Camera.RotateX(-lasty*0.01); 
    lastx = (float)x;
    lasty = (float)y;
    Display();
}
```

Comment: Just a guess...lastx & lasty aren't initialized to anything meaningful, so the first call to mouseMovement starts with two random subtractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing, If you're tracking all mouse movement you'll need to either catch when the mouse enters or leaves the window, or simply discard any jumps larger than a certain amount.

Let's say that the mouse leaves the right edge of the window, and reenters the left edge of the window. The code you've shown is going to jump.

Unless there's a reason not to, I'd make the last variables static and add an if statement similar to this(not tested :) )...

```
void mouseMovement(int x, int y) 
{
    static float lastx = 0.0;
    static float lasty = 0.0;

    lastx = (float)x - lastx;
    lasty = (float)y - lasty;

    if((abs((int)lastx)>10)||(abs((int)lasty)>10)
    {
        lastx = (float)x;
        lasty = (float)y;
        return;
    }

   //the rest remains the same
```

The logic goes...
Any event it sees, that isn't near the last event it saw, just resets the variables and waits for another event.

That really isn't an elegant solution for a mouse control, but at this point in your coding it is probably understandable, and will do what you want.

Comment: It works but I still do not understand the logic. At beginning my cursor is not out of the window. So why does it jump?

Comment: Because it hasn't seen the mouse move yet, and it has record that it was last seen at (0,0). From the controllers perspective it starts out thinking the mouse is in the top left corner of the window.

Answer (score 1):

Move the cursor to the middle of the screen *before* you start accepting data. And ensure that `lastx` and `lasty` are properly initialized.

I am 90% sure it's FPP camera, and you move the cursor to the middle of the screen manually. So it happens it starts in a down-right corner of the window, then is moved, which reports as a delta. It can also be the fact that `lastx` and `lasty` are initialized on first read, and prior to that they contain garbage.

Comment: I initialized them as 0.0.

Comment: So what should lastx and lasy be initialized?

Comment: If you can just move the cursor to the middle of the screen before moving the camera, `0.0` should be fine

Comment: What are your `x, y` coordinates for the middle of the screen? Are you using FPP camera, because you haven't confirmed that?

Comment: I don't know what FPP camera is, I searched it in internet but I couldn't find anything? Do you mean FPS camera? For middle screen:

          cout << glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_WIDTH) / 2;
          cout <<glutGet(GLUT_WINDOW_HEIGHT) / 2; 
the result is 150 150.

Comment: You need a better internet. FPP stand for First Person Perspective, and yes, it's used in First Person Shooter games. Set the `lastx` and `lasty` to `glutGet(..._WIDTH)` and `HEIGHT, appropriately.

Comment: It doesn't matter what kind of a camera it is. You only want to respond to meaningful events, and the initial jump from 0,0 to MouseX,MouseY isn't meaningful. The camera could simply be rotating a skybox full of nudie pics, but still you don't want it jumping around. :)